# operator= calls other operator= repeatedly

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I have 2 classes `HttpRequest` and `RequestParser` both implementing the operator=. Each have a variable referencing to `HttpRequest` and `RequestParser` as so:

```
class HttpRequest : public Message {
    private:
        std::string _method;
        std::string _path;
        bool _requestReceived;

        RequestParser _parser;

        ...

HttpRequest &HttpRequest::operator=(HttpRequest const &rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        _method = rhs._method;
        _path = rhs._path;
        _parser = rhs._parser;
    }
}
```

```
class RequestParser {
    private:
        std::stringstream _inReceive;
        bool _headersReceived;

        HttpRequest &_request;

        ...
RequestParser &RequestParser::operator=(RequestParser const &rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        _inReceive << rhs._inReceive.str();
        _headersReceived = rhs._headersReceived;
        _request = rhs._request;
    }
}
```

The problem is that they each call operator= repeatedly.

```
    #28 0x5641ead38f57 in RequestParser::operator=(RequestParser const&) srcs/http/RequestParser.cpp:98
    #29 0x5641ead368f1 in HttpRequest::operator=(HttpRequest const&) srcs/http/HttpRequest.cpp:64
    #30 0x5641ead38f57 in RequestParser::operator=(RequestParser const&) srcs/http/RequestParser.cpp:98
    #31 0x5641ead368f1 in HttpRequest::operator=(HttpRequest const&) srcs/http/HttpRequest.cpp:64
    #32 0x5641ead38f57 in RequestParser::operator=(RequestParser const&) srcs/http/RequestParser.cpp:98
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: You can't copy reference and instead copying object itself. Probably need to use `HttpRequest *_request;` instead of reference.

Comment: `operator=` normally makes no sense for classes with reference memebers, since references can't be modified to point to a different object (assigning to them instead assigns to the target object). For that reason, reference members are a bad thing, use pointers instead.

Comment: Reference members variables are okay if-and-only-if it is okay that the class is not assignable (no `operator=`, so the compiler can help you when you violate that constraint by mistake), or if it is okay to assign to what the reference refers (unlikely, but if so makes it tricky due to object lifespan entanglement).

Comment: It looks quite odd that either one of these is a member of the other. I would expect a `HttpParser` to create a new `HttpRequest`, and `HttpRequest` to be completely unaware of `HttpParser`.

Comment: Do you understand why the infinite recursion happens? Nobody can tell you how to fix this, only you could possibly know that, because only you know the complete semantics of how all classes in your program are related to each other, semantically, and the correct fix depends on that. The few isolated code snippets shown here offer little in terms of determining that.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, I completely forgot about references and how they worked. I'm going to change the semantic of my code as suggested by @molbdnilo